# Binary Search and Sorting an Array by alphabetical order C++

Tags: c++

I have a dynamic array which contains a contact number and name. I was wondering how to do a binary search for the  name. Let's say I have 20 contacts and I want to find the number of the contact with name `"John"`.

Here is the data structure:

```
struct Contact
{
    int ContactNumber,Fax;
    string Name, Email;
    PhoneNumber Phone;
    Address anAddress;
};
```

I have:

```
Contact * ptrFirst = & arrofCont[0];
Contact * ptrLast = & arrofCont[MAX - 1];
```

that contains the contact name and number and address etc. I guess those can be used as a first and last but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Normally you'd use `std::sort` and `std::binary_search` for sorting and searching respectively. Both take custom comparators.

Comment: You couldn't find anything? Hard to believe, sorry.

Comment: @user3297659 Show the definition of the array

Comment: @chris: `std::lower_bound` may be also useful as OP wants to have the associated number of `"John"`.

Comment: @Jarod42, Oops, that's right. A boolean value isn't all too helpful for that goal.

Comment: Well I have :

Contact * ptrFirst = & arrofCont[0];
Contact * ptrLast = & arrofCont[MAX - 1];

That contains the contact name and number and adress etc.

I guess those can be used as a first and last but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: I suspect your solution is a little bit overkill. Before thinking about a way to optimize your search just implement it the naive way. Then, run a performance test and see where and HOW to optimize.
Maybe your UI drawing routine is order of magnitude slower than an O(N) linear search over 1000-2000 contact numbers :-) Donald Knuth about early optimizations:
http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

Comment: I keep getting an error when i try to edit it so ill post it here: 

`struct Contact
{
 int ContactNumber,Fax;
 string Name, Email;
 PhoneNumber Phone;
 Address anAddress;
};

Comment: @user3297659, Note that the `last` you pass into standard algorithms is one-past-the-end, not the last element itself. Also note that `&arrofCont[MAX]` is (maybe debatably) undefined behaviour, so you'd have to use something like `arrofCont + MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort or binary search your array to do what you want.
Just use [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Company
{
    std::string name ;
    std::string number ;    
};

struct HasName
{
    HasName (const std::string &name) : name (name) {}
    bool operator () (const Company &company) {
        return company.name == name ;
    }

    std::string name ;
};

int main (void)
{
    std::vector <Company> companies ;
    // Fill up the vector...

    std::vector <Company>::const_iterator citer ;
    citer = std::find_if (companies.cbegin (), companies.cend (), HasName ("John")) ;

    if (citer != companies.cend ()) {
        std::cout << citer->number << "\n" ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: how does this find the number of the contact with name "John"? probably, something more is needed...

Comment: just return number of "John" now. (also correct the search, you are not searching for Oracle's but for John's numer)

Comment: @piotruś There we go, even though this is needlessly inefficient, it does what the OP asks for.

Comment: @jiv902 OP wants a number of "John", it was my mistake to think initially that he wants number of Contacts with "John" in name. Please let me correct code above, can I?

Comment: @piotruś Rather than including all the sorting and searching, I'm settling for `std::find_if`. There is no need to sort and search the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses a lambda expression to compare a pair of elements of the array
It corresponds to your original post before you updated it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct Contact
{
   std::string name;
   int number;
};

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 3; // or N = 20 or you can use name MAX instead of N
    Contact *p = new Contact[N] { { "B", 2 }, { "A", 1 }, { "C", 3 } };

    auto less_by_name = []( const Contact &c1, const Contact &c2 ) 
    { 
        return ( c1.name < c2.name ); 
    };

    std::sort( p, p + N, less_by_name);

    auto it = std::lower_bound( p, p + N, Contact( { "B", 0 } ), less_by_name );

    if ( it != p + N ) std::cout << "The number of \"B\" is " << it->number << std::endl;

    delete []p;
}
```

Or you can make the functor as a member of your class. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct Contact
{
   std::string name;
   int number;
   static bool less_by_name( const Contact &c1, const Contact &c2 )
   {
        return ( c1.name < c2.name );
   }
};

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 3; // or N = 20 or you can use name MAX instead of N
    Contact *p = new Contact[N] { { "B", 2 }, { "A", 1 }, { "C", 3 } };

    std::sort( p, p + N, Contact::less_by_name);

    auto it = std::lower_bound( p, p + N, Contact( { "B", 0 } ), Contact::less_by_name );

    if ( it != p + N ) std::cout << "The number of \"B\" is " << it->number << std::endl;

    delete []p; 
}
```

As for your definitions

```
Contact * ptrFirst = & arrofCont[0];
Contact * ptrLast = & arrofCont[MAX - 1];
```

then if you will change them the following way

```
Contact * ptrFirst = arrofCont;
Contact * ptrLast  = arrofCont + MAX;
```

then they will correspond to

```
Contact * ptrFirst = p;
Contact * ptrLast  = p + N;
```

relative to my examples of code.

Comment: You may use `std::vector` instead of `new`, and then `begin()`, `end()`.

Comment: @Jarod42  It is not me. It is he who may use std::vector. But as he said he needs code for a dynamically allocated array.